# How to convert matrix to string array?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

Assume I have the following values:

```
A:  [2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0] 
B:  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
C:  [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
D:  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

These values represent the occurrences of chars (A, B, C, D) in a two row char matrix, each row is 6 chars long. It should be interpreted like this:

- A appears 2 times in the first column, and 2 times in the 3rd column.
- B appears 1 time in the 2nd column and 1 time in the 6th column.
- and so on...

The resulting two rows matrix looks like:

```
[A, B, A, C, C, D]
[A, C, A, D, A, B]
```

I don't have any idea how to get the string array from the matrix. Kindly help.

Comment: programming using JAVA

Comment: You need to put the code that you have

Comment: Since it is a research work, I can not publish the code before I complete my thesis..

Comment: You would need to put part of your code to explain your problem. As of now your problem is not clear.

Comment: Just tell me how to convert matrix to sting

Comment: How do you know it is ABACCD ACADAB and not ACACCD ABADAB? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: You don't need to "convert" the matrix. Start with empty matrix (containing six "" in each row). Use the information in A202010 (etc) to place the values in the matrix.

Comment: You don't even need to post your actual code, just post some dummy code.

Comment: As Artur indicated, you won't be able to uniquely reconstruct the string array because the ABCD arrays only specify a count and says nothing about which row in string array the character should appear.

Answer (score 0):

This just sketches the approach.
Clear names, look for how you would do it, what is repeated

- The result

  ```
  char[][] resultRows = new char[2][6];
  ```
- What is repeated; what must be collected etcetera:

  ```
  // The same work for every column:
  for (int columnI = 0; columnI < 6; ++columnI) {
      int resultRowI = 0;
      for (int letterRowI = 0; letterRowI < 4; ++letterRowI) {
          int n = rows[letterRowI][columnI];
  ```
- What to do with an input value.

  ```
          while (n > 0) {
              resultRows[resultRowI][columnI] = letter[letterRowI];
              ++resultRowI;
              --n;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Output the result.

Of course one should try the next time to find a solution oneself.
Possibly be doing the solution "on paper" / in mind.